# Protecting Live USB from Windows Viruses

Tags: partitioning

Ever since I started using linux, I said good bye to windows forever.  I always carry live usb linux alongwith me (these days, I am trying LXLE for instance).

I use the same pen drive to copy data.  Though, windows viruses do not affect the linux OS but when I connect the pen drive to windows OS they infect the other data files.

Is there anyway to protect the pen drive itself from windows viruses?  I was thinking of creating two partitions:

1. ext4
2. fat32

the second partition can contain some sort of software using which I can transfer data to ext4 partition as I understand ext4 partitions are secure from windows viruses.

does this appear feasible?

Comment: But you can't mount ext4 partition on Windows.

Comment: right, that's why the second partition fat32 which can be used to mount ext4.

Comment: How did you mount ext4 partition via fat32 in windows?

Comment: there is something known linux partition reader.  Its able to read ext partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you proposed is complex and not portable (Windows will need special extra drivers to read ext, and they are not stable).
**There is no trouble**, use the freeware Windows software [Ninja Pendisk](http://www.ninjapendisk.com/).
Ninja Pendisk is fully portable, self-contained, requires no installation and protects your Windows machine from any virus or malware trasmitted via USB:
 (from the website)

> besides removing known virulent files, this tool will also immunize
>   your pendisk and create a folder called autorun.inf with special
>   protection permissions to protect your pendisk from being infected
>   again when plugged on contaminated computers

I always used it and it's very handy!

Comment under here if you have other questions and press the UP arrow if I'm of any help.
Have a safe day.

Answer (score 1):

You can install some Linux antivirus to scan the windows files.

There are many antivirus than you can use

To Install Clamav

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

To update pattern files

```
sudo freshclam
```

To scan all your filesystem and remove infected files

```
sudo clamscan --infected --remove --recursive /
```

To download test virus

```
wget http://www.eicar.org/download/eicar.com
```

To uninstall

```
sudo apt-get remove clamav
```

But you can use a frontend GUI that works with calmav called AntiVirus Scanner(avscan). you can download from [here](http://freecode.com/projects/avscan).

Moreover there are many GUI frontends for calmav. you can check this menu [here](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/third-party-tools/3rdparty-gui/) and choose one of them but i advise you by the one above(avscan)

If you want to use other GUI i advise to use [comodo](http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/antivirus-for-linux.php).Comodo has a free, modern, easy to use anti-virus program for various GNU/Linux distributions including Ubuntu 12.04.x.y 32 and 64 bit LTS. The graphical user interface is easy to learn how to use.